# Is it safe to exercise barefoot?

Tags: exercise, home-exercise, hiit, shoes, barefoot

I don’t like to wear shoes in-house. Is it safe to exercise barefoot on carpet?

What if I use a thin mattress on top of the carpet?

What about HIIT exercises like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vy9WKyN1rig&list=PLq5we3XE7pZ4oK5qy0eMmmu4b-wen7ohK&index=1 ?

In my whole life, I’ve almost always exercised barefoot and did not have a problem. But I haven’t done that much exercising in my life in the first place. (I’m guessing two 1-hour sessions a month on average in recent years with a LOT of variance.) I’m in my early twenties, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Making sure that the area is clean and clear of any small objects that may cause you to hurt your feet or cause cuts would be important. Likewise making sure that furniture it out of the way and that the surface has enough purchase for your feet.

For example, carpet would provide a much better surface than hardwood (you mentioned carpeting, so that’s good)

For high intensity interval workouts this shouldn’t be a major issue unless you are planning to use heavy kettlebells or dumbbells in your workouts which could cause risk if you slip or lose your balance.

As all high intensity exercise comes with risk, there is no way to eliminate it, however doing many of these body weight motions in bare feet shouldn’t pose a massively higher risk to your safety.

An exercise mat or large yoga mat might present a good investment as well for this, although maintaining a level stable surface on carpet would be difficult. (In regards to using a mattress I would refrain from that as it would be an unsecured surface that could shift while you’re working out)